# Values get corrupted in template tag

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am developing an app which enables me to show multiple markers when I click on the markers it should show me an image along with some details.

My current code is :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(

             contentString = 
             '<div id="content">'+
            '<p>'+ 'sensor image:'  +'<br/>' +
            '<img src="{% static "test/imgs/sen1.jpg" %}">'+
            + '<br/>' +
            'sensor light level :' + j[i][4] +'<br/>' +
            'sensor battery level :' + j[i][5] +
            '</p>'+
            '</div>'
        );
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
```

and I get the desired output:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/izR9G.jpg

I have an array, j which contains name of the image I want to load, previously i hardcoded the url

```
'<img src="{% static "test/imgs/sen1.jpg" %}">'+
```

I tried to make this dynamic by using

```
'<img src="{% static "test/imgs/'+ j[i][3] +'.jpg" %}">'+
```

But i got an error , on using F12 it appears
GET localhost:8000/static/test/imgs/'%2B%20j%5Bi%5D%5B3%5D%20%2B'.jpg 404 (Not Found)

a lot of garbage was generated instead of the value sen1.

I am not able to understand why this is happening and would like some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simple:

```
'<img src="/static/test/imgs/' + j[i][3] + '.jpg">'
```

You can't use dynamic render for jinja templates, because this render run only first time.